# R using distinct() with variable column header

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
> my.df <- data.frame(uid=c(1,1,3),somevalue=c("x","y","z"))
> my.df
   uid somevalue
1    1         x
2    1         y
3    3         z
```

I want:

```
  uid somevalue
1   1         y
2   3         z
```

I can't  use

```
distinct(my.df, uid, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

because the variable name `"uid"` could change. However I have the variable name stored as a string.

So I get

```
> iKey <- "uid"
> distinct(my.df, iKey, .keep_all= TRUE)
  uid somevalue
1   1         x
2   1         y
3   3         z
Warning message:
Trying to compute distinct() for variables not found in the data:
- `iKey`
This is an error, but only a warning is raised for compatibility reasons.
The operation will return the input unchanged.
```

How can I get distinct() to use the value of `iKey` and not take it literally?

Comment: `distinct` will return 1st value of duplicate. See `distinct(my.df, uid, .keep_all= TRUE)` which is `x` for `uid = 1`. Do you want to return the last value of duplicate i.e `y` instead ?

Comment: I don't mind, I can use either duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.data` pronoun :

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(my.df, .data[[iKey]], .keep_all= TRUE)

#  uid somevalue
#1   1         x
#2   3         z
```

Or convert `iKey` to symbol with `sym` and evaluate it `!!`

```
distinct(my.df, !!sym(iKey), .keep_all= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyselect `across`/`all_of` idiom works as well:

```
distinct(my.df, across(all_of(iKey)), .keep_all= TRUE)
```